# Enable blob cache on multi server farm

Tags: image, blob-cache

I need to enable blob cache on my farm, to use image renditions, do I need to enable this on all servers? do I need to do this manual if I have 10 servers? Do I need to do this on application servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable it on any server running the Foundation Web Application service.  The path must be available on all servers with this service.

I built a F/OSS solution to help with this -- https://blobcache.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 1):

Just enable this on your front end servers. Blob cache (by default) caches stuff relevent to end user queries.

just remember to put the cache on dedicated disks :)